# Using shell commands at the same time as a while loop.

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a game that is for teaching people python, so I'm controlling it by assigning variables, calling functions etc. screeps.com is a similar concept, except it's Javascript, and this is Python. The problem I'm having though, is that I have to use a while loop to refresh the screen, but commands given through the shell can't be executed while the while loop is running. For example, I want to be able to input x += 5, and have the player move to the right. So what I need is a way to refresh the screen at the same time as executing shell commands. Also, I'm using Python 3.4. Thanks in advance.

```
    import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('My game')

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
crashed = False
pImg = pygame.image.load('player.png')


def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(pImg, (x,y))

x =  (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)
x_change = 0
car_speed = 0

while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True   
    gameDisplay.fill(black)
    car(x,y)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use two threads 
1) Thread - Update the display periodically based on inputs
2) Thread - Process inputs and update the shared variables

Answer (score 0):

Threads are the right way to do this. Make sure you import thread at the top.

```
import thread

consoling = False

def threadedConsole():
    global consoling
    consoling = True
    exec(raw_input(">>> "))
    consoling = False

while True:
    #Game loop
    if not consoling:
        thread.start_new_thread(threadedConsole,())
```

Comment: I get the error of:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\CREATIONS\game.py", line 43, in <module>
    threading.start_new_thread(threadedConsole,())
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'start_new_thread'
Is it possible that start_new_thread, isn't the correct term?

Comment: Don't import threading, import thread instead. They are two separate modules with threading being the more advanced one, which you don't need.